# Refresh images the same name

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have applications on WP8, it contains images loaded from the server. Pictures are changing on server but have the same name and the same url. After the change, the phone still displays the previous pictures. How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to built in resource caching, which affects both remote requests as well as requests for local image resources in your application. When declaring your image control markup, you can disable caching by creating its source property manually. For instance:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ContentPath}"
                     CreateOptions="IgnoreImageCache" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the phone caches the images that are downloaded. If you wanna set a new image you have to "clean" the image source. Your questions is not given me inave information, but from what i understand, one simple converter should do the trick:

```
 public class CacheImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {       
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
         {
            string path = value as string;
            Uri imageFileUri = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
            BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(imageFileUri);
            return bm;
          }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
             throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**XML**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <imgConv:CacheImageConverter x:Key="ConvertNew" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

...

```
<Image Source="{Binding strPath, Converter={StaticResource ConvertNew}}"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't accomplish anything. The problem is due to caching and making a request to the same URL. Either the web server needs to issue more informative caching directives or the phone needs to ignore its cache. This code will still output the cached image asset.